# Drive is not opening

Tags: mount, hard-drive, directory, disk

I am new at linux/Ubuntu.
I have installed Linux budgies(Ubuntu flavour) 16.04 LTE before 1 month,
now i am stucked in a serious problem,

Drives other than Computer is not opening, while double clicking on them.
Whenever i click the Explorer is just refreshes, and nothing happens.

[Screenshot is here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCHsU.png)

And in my Computer Drive, in Media folder there is only 1 folder is showing,'dipak' which is my ubuntu username:

[media folder screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83WHl.png)

I Don't want to lost my data, and while going in windows operating system, all drives are opening.

Please help.

Comment: Do you set-up password. I am facing same issue but asking for password on double click. Once i entered password it open other drives.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see the option for your drive?, if you can, then try moving your drive data on a windows pc, and format your drive as ext-2 format on ubuntu